# How to grab value from TextView and divide it by number of years?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm a nooby to Android Development. I'm starting out building my first mortgage app. I'm having trouble finding out how to grab value from a textview connected with my seekbar and divide it by 12 which is the number of months in a year. The seekbar holds the user interest rate generated by them touch/dragging the seekbar. If anyone can help it would be great! Thanks! Feel free to lead me to any tutorials that may help as well.

```
package com.example.mrstreet.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class morcal extends Activity {

    public double currentLoanAmount; // loan amount entered by user
    public EditText loan_amount; //accepts user input for loan amount

    public SeekBar InterestRate; //SeekBar
    public TextView currentInterestRate; //Interest rate reflected from SeekBar


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_morcal);


        loan_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loan_amount);  //Get Loan EditText

        loan_amount.addTextChangedListener(loan_amountWatcher); //Loan Amount Text Watcher

        InterestRate = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.InterestRate);
        currentInterestRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentInteresetRate);

        InterestRate.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener());
        {
            //Listener for SeekBar
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar InterestRate,int progress, boolean fromUser){
            float decimalProgress = (float) progress / 10.0f;
            System.out.println("----  " + decimalProgress);
            currentInterestRate.setText(decimalProgress + "%"); //Seek Reflects to decimal progress
        }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar InterestRate){
        }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar InterestRate){
        });

    public TextWatcher loan_amountWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //called when user enters the number
        try
        {
            loan_amount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_morcal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



Here is my xml layout.
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".morcal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loan Amount"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loan_amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Interest Rate"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/InterestRate"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="%0.0"
            android:id="@+id/currentInteresetRate"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mortgage Period (Years)"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10yr"
                android:id="@+id/tenYearButton1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15yr"
                android:id="@+id/fifthteenYearButton2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30yr"
                android:id="@+id/thirtyYearButton3" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView has helper method getText which is similar to setText.

Comment: `EditText#getText` returns an `Editable` not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a number from your `TextView` then this should do it for you.

```
int loadAmount = Integer.parseInt(loan_amount.getText().toString());
```

Keep in mind that you also should restrict what the user can enter because the above will throw `NumberParseException` if a nonnumeric value is entered.

Comment: fyi:  inputType="number" on the TextView in xml

Comment: @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar InterestRate,int progress, boolean fromUser){
            float decimalProgress = (float) progress / 10.0f;
            System.out.println("----  " + decimalProgress);
            currentInterestRate.setText(decimalProgress + "%"); //Seek Reflects to decimal progress

            int currentInterestRate = Integer.parseInt(currentInterestRate.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
        //Listener for SeekBar
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar InterestRate,int progress, boolean fromUser){
        float decimalProgress = (float) progress / 10.0f;
        currentInterestRate.setText(String.valueOf(decimalProgress) + "%");
```

**EXPLANATION:**
When you use setText() to a textview, you need to pass to it a String, previously you were passing directly a float variable:

```
currentInterestRate.setText(decimalProgress + "%");
```

Using String.valueOf() you'll transform your decimalProcess float variable into a String that can be passed to setText() method:

```
currentInterestRate.setText(String.valueOf(decimalProgress) + "%");
```

Comment: Add more explanations to your answer.